# How to use group by with inner join in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to write a LINQ for the below query,

```
Select DIS.iDataItemID, DIS.iDataItemCurrentStatusID, DI.iDataTypeID, 
DI.iEmployeeID, DI.iEmployerID, DI.iLinkID, DI.iSystemID, DI.sData, 
DI.sEmployerCode, DI.sRecieptID, COunt(*)
from DataItem DI
INNER JOIN DataItemStatus DIS ON DIS.iDataItemID = 
DI.iDataItemID 
INNER JOIN RefDataItemStatus ON DIS.iDataItemCurrentStatusID 
= RefDataItemStatus.iDataItemStatusID
AND DIS.iDataItemCurrentStatusID = 1 AND DI.iDataTypeID = 8 
GROUP BY DIS.iDataItemID, DIS.iDataItemCurrentStatusID, DI.iDataTypeID, 
DI.iEmployeeID, DI.iEmployerID, DI.iLinkID, DI.iSystemID, DI.sData, 
DI.sEmployerCode, DI.sRecieptID
```

I have written the LINQ as below, Need to know how to use Group by on this,

```
from dataItem in msaDBContext.DataItem
                                 join dataItemStatus in msaDBContext.DataItemStatus on dataItem.iDataItemID equals dataItemStatus.iDataItemID
                                 join refDataItemStatus in msaDBContext.RefDataItemStatus on dataItemStatus.iDataItemCurrentStatusID equals refDataItemStatus.iDataItemStatusID
                                 where dataItemStatus.iDataItemCurrentStatusID == _processingStatus.iDataItemStatusID && dataItem.iDataTypeID == _dataType.iDataTypeID
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     iDataItemID = dataItem.iDataItemID,
                                     iDataItemCurrentStatusID = dataItemStatus.iDataItemCurrentStatusID,
                                     iDataTypeID = dataItem.iDataTypeID,
                                     iLinkID = dataItem.iLinkID,
                                     biRowVersion = dataItem.biRowVersion,
                                     sData = dataItem.sData,
                                     iEmployeeID = dataItem.iEmployeeID,
                                     iEmployerID = dataItem.iEmployerID,
                                     sEmployerCode = dataItem.sEmployerCode,
                                     iSystemID = dataItem.iSystemID,
                                     sReceiptID = dataItem.sRecieptID
                                 };
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to group up?

Comment: Perhaps my [SQL to LINQ Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786) might help you?